Sequences of arrows
Below are six sequences of arrows but one entry of the 5th sequence has been replaced by a question mark.

  ↑↑  →→  ↓↓  ↑  ←←
  
  ↑↑  →→  ↓  ←  ↓→
  
  ↑↑  →→  ↓  ←  ↓→
  
  ↑↑  →→  ↓↓  ←←
  
  ↓↓  ?  ↓→  ↑↑

  ←←  ↓  →→  ↓  ←←


What should replace the question mark?

Sounds familiar ?

@ACB I knew I had done similar before, but I didn't think it was that similar, so didn't care to check. Not easy to keep track of all puzzles from the past (ideas might be very similar).

I think the answer is

 →↑

Reasoning

 If you take a pen and follow the directions of the arrows, the result looks like the letters A,R,R,O,W,S in order. A combination of horizontal and vertical arrows seems to represent a diagonal line in that direction.
 


Shoot beat me to it!!!

I was drawing it on penpa+ oh well

Yes, this is correct!

I think the answer should be

 ↑→

For the same reason as @hexomino except that

 in every other diagonal combinations the up/down arrow precedes the left/right arrow.

